# Where can I find source code of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi NuGet package?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nuget

I have a few question regarding Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi NuGet package source code:

1. Where is located repository with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi Nuget package source code.
2. What commit id corresponds to version 5.2.3 of the NuGet package.
3. What *.nuspec file was used to create Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi package?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's the source for WebApi, but not sure where the .nuspec file is located in the repository. https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for the exact same thing and I finally found it. This page lists out the versions and where they correspond in the source. It is v.3.2.3 that maps to 5.2.3.

[Repository Tags and Version Numbers](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Repository%20Tags%20and%20Version%20Numbers)

Answer (score -1):

BY Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingANuGetPackageIn7EasyStepsPlusUsingNuGetToIntegrateASPNETMVC3IntoExistingWebFormsApplications.aspx

POSTED TO AVOID LINK ONLY ANSWER!

HOW I MADE MY OWN NUGET PACKAGE AND YOU SHOULD TOO BY Scott Hanselman:

Step 0 - Go get the NuGet.exe command line here. Put it in the Path or somewhere.

Step 1 - Make a folder for your new package, go there via the commmand line and run "nuget spec"

```
C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\AddMvc3ToWebForms>nuget spec 
Created 'Package.nuspec' successfully.

C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\AddMvc3ToWebForms>dir Package.nuspec 
Directory of C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\AddMvc3ToWebForms

02/15/2011  02:23 AM               813 Package.nuspec 
               1 File(s)            813 bytes
```

Now, I changed this file's name and edited it thusly.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>AddMvc3ToWebForms</id>
    <version>0.4</version>
    <authors>Scott Hanselman</authors>
    <owners>Scott Hanselman</owners>
    <iconUrl>http://www.hanselman.com/images/nugeticon.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>A totally unsupported way to quickly add ASP.NET MVC 3 support to your WebForms Application. Works on my machine.</description>
    <tags>MVC MVC3 ASP.NET WebForms</tags>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Step 2 - Add stuff to your Content Folder

Since I want my NuGet package to add stuff to folders in my target Web Application, I put whatever I want in a folder called Content. Anything in that will show up in the root of my target project. This can be CSS, JS, CS or VB files, whatever. These files will all get dropped onto the project your package is applied to.

In my project I took the folders from an MVC application and put them in my NuGet folder structure. So, Content, Controllers, Models, Scripts, Views. Copied them right over from an existing blank ASP.NET MVC project.

My NuGet directory where I'm building the package

Step 3 - Decide what needs to be Pre-Processed

However, when my HomeController shows up in your project, Dear Reader, I don't want it to be in the namespace ScottMvcApplication! You want it in MvcApplication54 or whatever your project name is. I need pre-process the source a little to use your project's context, names, namespaces, etc.

For the files I want pre-processed automatically by NuGet, I add a .pp extension. In my example, HomeController.cs.pp.

Preprocessor files with a .pp extension

Then I add a few tokens I want replaced at install-time for that package. For example $rootnamespace$ or $assemblyname$. You can use any Visual Studio Project Property per the NuGet docs.

```
namespace $rootnamespace$.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //snip
    }
}
```

Step 4 - Decide what XML elements need to be merged (usually into web.config)

The next preprocessing that is common is adding elements to web.config. This is a nice little feature of NuGet because you just need to make a web.config.transform with the new elements and it will automatically and non-destructively add (and remove) them as needed. Here's my web.config.transform, for reference. Note this is not a full web.config. This is the one I added to my package in the control folder.

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>   
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>    
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
     <assemblies>    
     <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />    
     <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />    
     <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />    
     <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />    
     <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />  
     </assemblies>
   </compilation>
    <pages>
       <namespaces>
         <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
         <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
       </namespaces>
     </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

     <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
          <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Step 5 - Add any PowerShell script you might need, especially for adding references

Almost done. Most package won't need much PowerShell, but some do. You can have an install.ps1 and an uninstall.ps1 and do lots of things. These go in a folder called Tools that's next to Content (not inside.)

Here's my install.ps1.

NOTE: Currently today there's no way to STOP the installation of a package while it's happening, so if you try to install mine on NuGet 1.0 I'll just warn you and ask you to uninstall. In the future there will likely be a pre-install or a dependency check. Hence the version check there.

param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

```
if ($host.Version.Major -eq 1 -and $host.Version.Minor -lt 1) 
{ 
    "NOTICE: This package only works with NuGet 1.1 or above. Please update your NuGet install at http://nuget.codeplex.com. Sorry, but you're now in a weird state. Please 'uninstall-package AddMvc3ToWebForms' now."
}
else
{
    $project.Object.References.Add("Microsoft.CSharp"); 
    $project.Object.References.Add("System.Web.Mvc"); 
    $project.Object.References.Add("Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure"); 
    $project.Object.References.Add("System.Web.WebPages"); 
    $project.Object.References.Add("System.Web.Razor"); 
    $project.Object.References.Add("System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"); 
}
```

Note that in (the future) NuGet 1.2 I won't need this code, I'll just add the references in my NuSpec file directly.

Step 6 - Pack it up

Go back to the command line and run nuget pack

```
C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\AddMvc3ToWebForms>nuget pack 
Attempting to build package from 'AddMvc3ToWebForms.nuspec'. 
Successfully created package 'C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\AddMvc3ToWebForms\AddMvc3ToWebForms.0.4.nupkg'.
```

Step 7 - Submit your package

Next, login to the NuGet Gallery (beta) and Contribute Your Package. Just walk through the wizard and upload the nupkg. You can also get an API Key and use the command line tool to do this automatically, perhaps as part of a build process.

Submitting my app to the NuGet Gallery

That's it. If you've got an open source librar

Comment: this is a guide to create NuGet package, but still it does not answer my question:

- where are sources used to create Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi NuGet package?
- what .nuspec they used?

Comment: What exactly does it not answer??

Comment: As I wrote above it does not answer my actual question: where I can find sources Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi NuGet package, what commit in git repository corresponds to version 5.2.3 of this package, and it there NuGet package creation commands in their build system?

Comment: Sorry, your english is difficult to understand. Here is the link to the 5.2.3 webapi nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi not sure if that helps.